# Remove colorbox (jQuery plugin) functionality only from one link, and then reapply it

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-plugins, timer, colorbox

I have two images, each of them wrapped in a link. I want to prevent colorbox from firing if I have been mousedown for more than a certain time. I noticed colorbox fires only on mouseup.

What I have been trying is to use a setTimeout function with a timer, then remove colorbox from that image and on mouseup "reattach" colorbox to that image so it can be fired again if the setTimeout doesn't occur.

HTML:

```
<a class="colorbox" href="..."><img src="..." /></a>

<a class="colorbox" href="..."><img src="..." /></a>
```

JS:

```
$('a.colorbox').colorbox();

var timer;

$('a.colorbox').on('mousedown', function(e) {

    var this_colorbox = $(this);

    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        this_colorbox.colorbox.remove();//this doesn't work
    }, 1500);

}).on('mouseup', function(e) {

    clearTimeout(timer);

});​

//"Reattach colorbox"??
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mydCn/

The problem I have is $.colorbox.remove(); (or my attempt this_colorbox.colorbox.remove();) removes colorbox from all the elements. How could I "Reattach colorbox" to that image instead of calling the function to every element again (doing so when there are lot of images would affect performance, no?)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it! I could do it just adding and removing classes. I'll publish the answer so it might be helpful to someone.

http://jsfiddle.net/mydCn/1/

```
$('a.colorbox').colorbox();

var timer;
var time_completed = 0;

$('a.colorbox').each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function(e) {
        if (time_completed === 0) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).removeClass('colorbox cboxElement');
        } else if (time_completed == 1) {
            $(this).addClass('colorbox cboxElement');
            time_completed = 0;
        }
    });

    $(this).on('mousedown', function(e) {
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            time_completed = 1;
        }, 500);
    }).on('mouseup', function(e) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        if (time_completed == 1) {
            $(this).click();
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: I'm glad you got it and thank you as well. It happen that I also need this kind of solution because I've been implementing this on a responsive design. I need to be able to disable the colorbox when the screen size cannot accommodate anymore the size of the colorbox. Then I have to turn on again the colorbox once the screen is enough to accommodate it.